# Validation Rule to prevent 'Closed Won' Opportunities from being edited once a checkbox is selected by AR Team. Or should I change workflow?

Tags: validation-rule

1. AND(
   $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',NOT(ISCHANGED(Opportunity_Closed__c)),OR(Opportunity_Closed__c = true))

**Got no errors with this but it seems to just autocheck the Opportunity closed box vs disallow non-admins to edit the opportunity.**

2. AND(
   ISPICKVAL( StageName , "4 - Closed Won"), AND(
   $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',NOT(ISCHANGED(Opportunity_Closed__c)),OR(Opportunity_Closed__c = true))

**Tried variations with picklist value being closed won and opportunity closed = true**

3. AND(
   ISPICKVAL(Stagename, 'Closed Won'),
   $User.Id != '005F000000431Qxxx1',
   $User.Id != '005F000000431Pxxx2',
   $User.Id != '005F0000005tuHxxx3',
   $Profile.ID != '00eF0000001B2gxxxC'
   )

**Wondering if I just need to exclude users who can't or adjust our AP user to their own profile like the above?**

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue with "ISCHANGED()" is that it only looks for changes on the *specific field* it's referring to; if you want to lock the *entire* record (except for admins), I'd try something like the following:

```
PRIORVALUE(IsWon) && $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"
```

(Yes, "IsWon" is an out-of-the-box Salesforce field, as is "IsClosed", but PRIORVALUE() is probably the important part here for your logic)